# How can I prevent UI hang, when my service runs a TimerTask?

Tags: android, service, freeze, timertask

I have a service which contains a Timer and TimerTask for receiving data from Webservice in periods of time. When my TimerTask runs, the UI hangs until the Webservice process complete. How can I put my task in a thread to prevent the UI hanging?

My code:

```
Timer timerSyncFull = new Timer();

class taskSyncFull extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hSyncFull.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };



final Handler hSyncFull = new Handler(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            procSyncFull();
            return false;
        }
    });

public void procSyncFull() {
        try {
            // My webservice process

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }



@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

timerSyncFull = new Timer();

timerSyncFull.schedule(new taskSyncFull(), 5*60*1000,
                        5*60*1000);

}
```

Comment: Arey you trying to update UI from your service or doing some stuff that performs some action on the UI?

Comment: no i do not do any stuff on UI. my service is separated from UI.

Comment: This is strange for me. because there should not be any relation between my activities and my services. Only my application hangs and other programs in OS works without hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code and my problem solved:

```
class taskSendMapMovements extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hhSendMapMovements.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };



    // /////////////////////

    final Runnable rSendMapMovements = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            procSendMapMovements();
        }
    };

    final Handler hhSendMapMovements = new Handler(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            performOnBackgroundThread(rSendMapMovements);

            return false;
        }
    });

    // /////////////////////

    public void procSendMapMovements() {
        try {    

        showToast("some text");
        //My Main Process    

        } catch (Exception e) {


        }
    }


@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        try {



            timerSendMapMovements = new Timer();


            timerSendMapMovements
                        .schedule(new taskSendMapMovements(),
                                10*60*1000,
                                10*60*1000);

            //

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "error running service: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "error running service: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


final Handler hToast = new Handler(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

            Toast.makeText(SrvDataExchange.this,
                    msg.getData().getString("msg"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

private void showToast(String strMessage) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", strMessage);
    msg.setData(b);
    hToast.sendMessage(msg);
}

public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {

                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTasks or attach your Handler to another Looper thread.

Comment: See the doc for sample code : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: `final Runnable r = new Runnable()
 {
  public void run()
  {
   procSyncFull();
  }
 };

 final Handler hSyncFull = new Handler(new Callback() {
  @Override
  public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
   Utilities.performOnBackgroundThread(r);

   return false;
  }
 });`

Comment: 01-07 13:46:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(4485): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: A Handler can only be created on Looper threads (special threads that can manage Handlers). See the AsyncTask example which is simpler.

Comment: my proc has a Toast. the exception is for that. how can i call Toast in it.

Comment: The exception above has nothing to do with Toasts. It's raised because you're creating a Handler whithin a wrong Thread.

Comment: I tested it by `Log.i("aa", "aa");` and everything is OK now. But i can not show Toast there. how can i add toast in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Simply invoke your procSyncFull() method in thread or asyncTask.

```
final Handler hSyncFull = new Handler(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Thread thread=new Thread()
            {
                public void run(){
                    procSyncFull();

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

private Handler webserviceCompletionHandler=new Handler()
{
    @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            return false;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use `AsyncTask` carry out your execution in `doInBackground()` and populate it  in `onPostExecute()`

[AsyncTask Example](http://android10.org/index.php/articlesother/239-android-application-and-asynctask-basics)